# django-oscar and multitenancy

Tags: django, django-oscar

I am researching Django Oscar for the ecommerce part of our business. One of the required features is that we need to host multiple shops on one Oscar instance, i.e. every shop owner should manage his own products, his own partners etc. And should not have access to other owner's content.

Google says it had this feature as of version 0.6: https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/releases-0.6/howto/multi_dealer_setup.html

But the current version (1.5 as of today) does not mention this feature. How to do multitenancy in later Oscar versions?

Comment: It will need customizations to the `Partner` module and related dashboard changes. See http://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/apps/partner.html

Comment: I don't know much about Oscar, but could tell you for what you are describing, you need a multi-tenant site in wich case you could use [django-tenant-schemas](https://github.com/bernardopires/django-tenant-schemas)  as the better aproach for that. I ignore if Oscar could be easily adapted for that.

Answer (score 5):

Oscar is great! I'm using the "multiple dealers" as described in here
https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/releases-0.6/howto/multi_dealer_setup.html

Until now I don't know another solution for multi-vendor.

Cheers,

## EDIT

The multiple dealers support is now possible in Oscar 0.6 without any
code changes, and called "permission-based dashboard". It's documented
here:
http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/apps/dashboard.html

"Staff users (users with is_staff==True) get access to all views in the dashboard. To better support Oscar’s use for marketplace scenarios, the permission-based dashboard has been introduced. If a non-staff user has the partner.dashboard_access permission set, they are given access to a subset of views, and their access to products and orders is limited."

Comment: If you could take the key info from the link and paste it into the answer that would be better than just a link.  If that URL were to become unavailable we'd lose the answer!

Comment: @sniper Thank you for the advice. I edited the answer with more new information and entered the key information. :)

Comment: @JoãoSizílio, I still don't understand how can multiple shops with multiple owners will be managed! I'm taking an overview of django-oscar.

Answer (score -1):

I know this post is old, however there is shuup if you are looking for a multi-vendor python based shop. It does basically everything Oscar does with a really responsive and productive admin.

https://www.shuup.com/

Comment: Oscar is an open source framework, and Shuup seems to be a commercial SAAS solution. How are they similar?

Comment: Shuup has an open source alternative, they can host it for you or you can host it yourself. Plus it has multi-vendor support built in